# Creating Mocha test suites programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm currently initializing a Mocha instance, to which I add files:

```js
const mocha = new Mocha({
  ui: "tdd",
  color: true,
});

const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, "one.test.js"));
mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, "two.test.js"));

mocha.run(...);
```

This obviously works as expected, as Mocha will `require` each file.

However, I'm now switching to generating JS code via Kotlin, which will output a single `.js` file.
The `addFile` approach becomes impossible.

I'm thus looking for a solution similar to:

```js
const mocha = new Mocha({
  ui: "tdd",
  color: true,
});

// Made up code
mocha.addSuite("My suite", () => {
  suite.test("my test", () => {
    // ...
  });
);

mocha.run(...);
```

Does Mocha offer an API that can help for this use case?